# If SSL/TSL is secure then why do terrorists use other alternatives instead?

Tags: tls, anonymity

Everywhere it is mentioned that `SSL/TLS` must be used because of the high security and privacy they provide.

My question is: if this is true then why terrorists and other people use other alternatives such as tox.chat instead?

Why `SSL/TLS` is not enough for them? does not this mean they are not as secure as claimed?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The question here is whom you want to be protected from. Using SSL/TLS with signed certificates is not that secure for someone who is messing with almost every state on earth. This is because the CA's can be forced to give the private key they issued to a specific website to the authorities. This enables the countries in which the CA's are located to decrypt the SSL traffic of this site. As many initellegence sevices cooperate with other "friendly" countries you can assume that encrypted based on signed certificates isn't that secure for a enemy of the state.

This can theoretically be gone around by issuing a self signed certificate but then the authorities can also go to a CA tell them to issue a signed certificate for that site and then switch the self signed certficate with the signed one they own in a MITm attack.

Even if we suggest that the authorities couldn't decrypt this traffic there sill is the problem that they can determine wich websites you visit. This is because the hostnames need to be resolved by DNS and DNS isn't encrypted in almost every case. And frequently visiting websites that are runned by ISIS or Al Qaida will definitifly put you on the lists of the intellegence even if they don't know what exactly you are doing out there.

They use TOR because tor adds another layer of encryption and also routes every packet over three hosts which makes it harder to obtain who initially wanted to visit a specific website.

Comment: CAs don't have the private key for the websites they secured with any remotely competent setup. They sign the *public* key, and do not learn the private key.

Comment: Your right I will correct that later,... Im in a meeting now

Comment: @davidb Also the self-signed certificate scenario that you describe is not feasible. In most self-signed certificate scenarios, both ends explicitly trust the exact same certificate, which cannot be intercepted, maliciously used, or otherwise bypassed by a third party without actually breaking the underlying crypto or TLS implementation.

Answer (score 4):

SSL/TLS is a solution to a specific problem in security and is not the all-in-one solution to all security problems one might have.

The scope of SSL/TLS is limited to securing the direct connection between two endpoints, i.e. client and a server. In protocols like HTTP the data exchange will be done this way, but in protocols like mail multiple hops are involved thus TLS does not provide end to end security. Same with other asynchronous message protocols where you don't have a direct connection between sender and recipient.

Apart from that TLS only provides encryption and tamper resistance. The privacy it provides is limited to protection against sniffing of the data. But it does not hide the endpoints of the connection, i.e. it does not provide any form of anonymity. It does also not protect data after the transport itself, so any information transferred with TLS will be available in clear at each of the endpoints. Thus you need to have additional tools to protect the data after the transport.

Comment: This is a great answer but I think you should maybe clarify what you mean by direct connection. It would be obvious to anyone with knowledge of how the Internet works, but in no way are we making direct connections to the websites that we're visiting. This is why SSL/TLS exists to begin with (to secure the communication between two nodes in the communication). It is however obvious to me that what you're referring to is the fact that TLS may become insufficient when there are more than two nodes that *require* communication with each other. I just thought that might use some clarification.